# JAVA - Split a String containing delimiter #| . String should also split if there are multiple occurances of #| like - #|#|

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which needs to be splitted into parts using #| as a delimiter. In some cases #|#| is appearing as well. It can go multiple times too.

Example String :

`kh73j563741043f4611144u3ol#|h73j5637411432vk651p4601#|sadf#|12342134#|ADHVSF#|1#|0#|0#|DFSFS#|SDFSBFSF#|2017-07-03 19:56:37.0#|3#|6#|#|SDJHSJKDSDKSDS ODHDO ODHSUDSD 34234234 PODSOF pfjfs`

What I have written :

`String input [] = line.split("\\#\\|");`

Above code is splitting the input into 13 different strings but the above code is not working for the last String where "#|#|"  is used as a delimeter.

How do I make a REGEX which could pass multiple instances of #| as a delimeter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wrap the pattern with a non-capturing group and set a `+` quantifier after it:

```
.split("(?:#\\|)+")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FF3j5O/1/)

Now, `(?:#\\|)+` matches 1 or more consecutive occurrences of a two-char sequence, `#` and `|`. Note you do not need to escape `#` (unless you want to use [`Pattern.COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) option (and you won't need it here with such a short pattern).